# Surjectivity of composite functions when 3 functions are involved

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Suppose that we have three $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ functions such as $ \ f$, $g$ and $h$. How should $f$ and $h$ be so that $f \circ g \circ h$ can be onto (surjective) given that $g$ is a one to one (injective) function?

Comment: Were you looking at any specific types of functions? There are some statements you can make in general. In particular, $f$ must be surjective, and the image of $h$ must be infinite. Note, however, that $h$ need not be injective or surjective. (Can you come up with examples of $f,g,h$ where $f\circ g \circ h$ is surjective but $h$ is not injective and/or surjective?)

Comment: @DanM. I'm inclined to say that the answer goes along the lines of listing all the possible combination of function types for $f$ and $h$ (onto, one to one and bijectivity) that can work out so that $f \circ g \circ h$ could still be an onto composition, but im not really sure, this was actually an exam question i had to skip.

Comment: @DanM. Thanks for the input. I think i've got some ideas from your first comment.

Comment: Ah OK. Thanks. Brian M. Scott's answer is a more complete explanation of what I was summarizing; $f$ must be surjective, but the only restriction on $h$ is that $h(\mathbb{Z})$ must be infinite. So $h$ can be surjective, injective, or neither, just so long as its image is infinite, and $f$ can be bijective or just surjective.

Comment: Whoops just saw your second comment! Glad to be of assistance! Two more notes: (1) I wasn't being precise in my first comment, and as Brian points out there's a stronger assumption you need on $f$ for this to be true: the restriction $f|_{\text{Image}(g\circ h)}$ must be a surjection. (2) If you think you're supposed to cook up an example of each of the six cases (hopefully not), then you'll probably find it easier in most cases to just assume $g$ is the identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s not much that you can say. Suppose that $h[\Bbb Z]=A$ and $g[A]=B$; $f\circ g\circ h$ is a surjection if and only if $f[B]=\Bbb Z$. This in turn requires that $B$ be infinite, which means that $A$ must be infinite. Thus, $h$ must have an infinite range $A$, and $f$ must map $g[A]$ onto $\Bbb Z$, but that’s about all that you can say in general. In particular, it’s not enough to require that $h$ and $f$ be surjections: a counterexample is obtained by taking $h$ and $f$ to be the identity functions and $g:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z:n\mapsto 2n$, in which case $f\circ g\circ h$ maps $\Bbb Z$ to the even integers.

Comment: $A$ would have to be infinite "even" if $g$ were not injective.

Comment: @Hagen: Very true. I have no idea what was running through my head when I phrased it that way.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Can't thank you enough again. I actually wasn't expecting the answer to be this easy to understand but it makes sense :)

Comment: @Diego: You’re welcome. This is another case in which all you really have to do is break it down properly. (Of course it isn’t always immediately obvious what *properly* is in any given case!)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott If we make $h[ \Bbb Z ] = A$ be an injective function  (with an infinite range in this case due to the parameter being infinite), can we say that $h$ need not be a surjection but can also be a one-to-one and/or a bijection function?

Comment: @Diego: $h$ can be absolutely any function from $\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Z$ with an infinite range.